# Display two column from JSON using AJAX in jQuery auto complete in a table format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Currently working on jQuery auto complete where I can able to generate data from  JSON single column data, but I want two values should be displayed label and descirption

this is my json

```
[{"id":"Emirates College of Technology- UAE","label":"COL000001","value":"COL000001"}, {"id":"Al Khawarizmi nternational ollege- UAE","label":"COL000002","value":"COL000002"}, {"id":"Syscoms ollege","label":"COL000003","value":"COL000003"}, {"id":"Abounajm Khanj Pre-Uni enter","label":"COL000004","value":"COL000004"}, {"id":"Advanced lacement","label":"COL000005","value":"COL000005"}, {"id":"Al Buraimi College Uni Clge)","label":"COL000006","value":"COL000006"}, {"id":"Al-Ain Community ollege","label":"COL000007","value":"COL000007"}, {"id":"AMA Computer ollege","label":"COL000008","value":"COL000008"}, {"id":"Arab Academy for Bankg nd Fin","label":"COL000009","value":"COL000009"}, "id":"ARABACDSCITECHMARTIMETRNS","label":"COL0000010","value":"COL0000010"}, "id":"Arapahoe Community College","label":"COL0000011","value":"COL0000011"}, {"id":"Other","label":"Other","value":"Other"}]
```

Here is my jquery code

```
$("#scl_name").autocomplete({
highlightClass: "bold",
 source: function( request, response ) {
      var regex = new RegExp(request.term, 'i');
      //var filteredArray = filteredArray.slice(0,10);
    $.ajax({
        url: "json/dummy.json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {term: request.term},
        success: function(data) {
            response($.map(data, function(item) {
                if(regex.test(item.label)){
                    var html="";
                    html += "<table>";
                    html += "   <tr>";
                    html += "       <td>"+addslashes(item.label)+"</td>";
                    html += "       <td>"+addslashes(item.id)+"</td>";
                    html += "   </tr>";
                    html += "</table>";
                    return {
                        value: html,
                        value: item.id,
                        value: item.label
                    };
                }
            }));
        },

    });
},
select: function(event, ui) {
     $('#school_Name').val(ui.item.id);
}
});   
 });

 function addslashes(string) {
    return string.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\').
    replace(/\u0008/g, '\\b').
    replace(/\t/g, '\\t').
    replace(/\n/g, '\\n').
    replace(/\f/g, '\\f').
    replace(/\r/g, '\\r').
    replace(/'/g, '\\\'').
    replace(/"/g, '\\"');
 }
```

With this above code I am getting the data, for first column but not for second column in second column i am getting the value as undefined

[image]

what I am doing wrong here?

```
ReferenceError: Item is not defined
html += "       <th>" + Item + "</th>";
```

Comment: Have you checked that your `id` isn't undefined? You can log your results (or individual items) in the console to make sure data is correct... Another thing, your are returning an object from `$.map` where you set the **same** key `value` to 3 different things, which won't work...

Comment: could you please guide me i am new to ajax and json getting confused :(

Comment: You should use the `console` and other developer tools of your browser to inspect and debug your app. [Here's a useful read](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging). Also, you are giving a lot of code and asking for a broad inspection of your problem, which isn't going to cut it :). You do your best to try to fix it, determine the most exact position of the problem you can and then edit your question here again with more specifics and we'll be happy to help :)

Comment: Can you show how you are displaying the table?

Comment: I have updated the image

Comment: Not visually, I mean **where** in the code you are creating the HTML? What does the `response` function do? Your problem is most likely that you are returning an object where `value` is the `label` because you are overriding the rest by reusing the same key `value` in: `return {
                        value: html,
                        value: item.id,
                        value: item.label
                    };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, here it goes my help. When dealing with JSON is better if you can be sure that you are receiving what you are expecting, first of all. To do this you have a function called .success on your AJAX response and this parses each JSON item (this will be your first item: {"id":"Emirates College of Technology- UAE","label":"COL000001","value":"COL000001"})

To be sure you are receiving the id, label and value elements I will do something like this inside your success function:

console.log(item.id);

```
console.log(item.label);
console.log(item.value);
```

or just directly

```
console.log(item); // this will be presented as an object you can examine on your chrome browser, for example.
```

if you are sure you are getting the values on the client then I will be fixing the problem you are having when returning from the function, as you may know you can only return one value, not three:

```
return {
                        value: html,
                        value: item.id,
                        value: item.label
                    };
```

Change it to :

```
return {
                        value: html,
                    };
```

as you seem to be creating the entire value already. If this is not your issue, please post back again.

If you want to add a heading this will do it:

```
var html = "";
    html += "<table>";
    html += " <tr>";
    html += "   <th>" + Title + "</th>";
    html += "   <th>" + Description + "</th>";
    html += " </tr>"; 
    html += " <tr>"; 
    html += "   <td>" + addslashes(item.label) + "</td>";
    html += "   <td>" + addslashes(item.id) + "</td>";
    html += " </tr>"; 
    html += "</table>";
```

Comment: I want to add heading and key selector for example if i type a that a should be in color is that possible 

html += "<th>";
      html += "  <td>"+Label+"</td>";
      html += "  <td>"+Descirption+"</td>";
      html += "</th>";

Comment: You can change that HTML to whatever you want it to be, is just HTML at that point. Keep in mind that you need to keep adding HTML, if you do just what you posted you will end up with only that HTML, you need to add that HTML and keep adding the rest of the previous HTML.

Comment: can you please create chat session

Comment: is this correct for adding 

    var html = "";
    html += "<table>";
 html += "   <tr>";
 html += "       <th>" + Title + "</th>";
    html += "       <th>" + Description + "</th>";
    html += "   </tr>";
    html += "   <tr>";
    html += "       <td>" + addslashes(item.label) + "</td>";
    html += "       <td>" + addslashes(item.id) + "</td>";
    html += "   </tr>";
    html += "</table>";

Comment: It is difficult for me to read the code in here so I pasted the code you just wrote on the answer and better formatted ( you probably have it like that already, just wanted to put it nicely formatted). You are on the right path there!

Comment: i am getting an error if i added the th ReferenceError: Item is not defined
 

html += "       <th>" + Item + "</th>";

Comment: Item is the "object" (the thing) that holds all the details (properties) so you can't just print the item object, you need to use his properties. The properties for item are the different values for the JSON you are receiving, like item.id, item.label and item.value. You can print item to the console when using the appropriate parser (ie a web browser or other tools).